# TypeMismatch exception in Java code

Tags: java

The error I get is

> Type mismatch at variable 'first'".

First is an integer. Please help me figure out the problem

```
import java.util.*;
public class Hello {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

       String ip,firstpart,lastpart;
       int first,last,strlen,newvar;
       Scanner scanner=new Scanner(System.in);


       first=scanner.nextInt();
       if(scanner.hasNextInt()){
           last=scanner.nextInt();
       }
       else 
           last=0;
       ip=scanner.nextLine();
       firstpart=ip.substring(first);
       strlen=firstpart.length();
       newvar=strlen-last;
       lastpart=firstpart.substring(0,newvar);
       System.out.println(lastpart);

    }
}
```

Comment: What is the exact error?

Comment: What input are you providing?

Comment: Please post your stack trace so we can see exactly what's happening.

Comment: Can't reproduce, this code compiles.

Comment: what you are trying to do? what are the inputs, what you need as output?

Comment: For example, ip string = marshmallow , first = 2 and last = 3 the output should be rshmal (ie); removing first two characters and last 3 characters in a string.

Answer (score -1):

```
first=scanner.nextInt();
```

Replace above code with below code

```
first=Integer.parseInt(scanner.next());
```

Comment: No, `nextInt()` should be called. Why else would the `Scanner` class contain that method?

Comment: I changed the code ..instead of using all those if else statements..i used **scan.next()** for getting the string. It worked thereafter.